# What is a good way to direct console output to Text-box in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, textbox

In C#, what is a good way to direct console output to Text-box in Windows Form?

If I have an existing program that has console.WriteLine , do I need to overload the function in Windows Form Text-box?

Comment: you want to redirect Console.WriteLine to a TextBox?

Comment: Yes, so instead of seeing lines in command, I want to see them on textbox.

Comment: Right, I think MessageBox might be the right term here.

Comment: @SndLt at the moment I think you mean if you write `Console.WriteLine("Something")` in your code, it should pop-up a MessageBox?

Comment: `MessageBox` is that thing that pops up and requires user input, `TextBox` is an input field. Neither of them will make your users very happy I think :)

Comment: I don't think he cares about the input, he wants to embed a console into a form, and have the console displayed in a text box. Pretty simple idea, but not that simple to execute.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a text writer which writes to a text box:

```
    public class TextBoxWriter : TextWriter
    {
        TextBox _output = null;

        public TextBoxWriter (TextBox output)
        {
            _output = output;
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            _output.AppendText(value.ToString());
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
```

And redirect Console output to this writer:

```
        //...

        public Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.SetOut(new TextBoxWriter(txtConsole));
            Console.WriteLine("Now redirecting output to the text box");
        }
```

Comment: You should really override Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count) as well or it is going to suck mud.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that was exactly the overload I needed to implement to make it far more efficient.

Comment: i have 2 textboxes, in 2 userControl forms. Am using like   _writer = new RedirectConsole(textBox1) and  _writer = new RedirectConsole(textBox2). a single writeline command in one form is showing in other textbox in another form as well

Answer (score -3):

```
button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      // Do stuff
   }
   catch(Exception exception)
   {
      // Couldn't do stuff. Log the exception.
      myTextBox.Text += "\n" + exception.Message;
   }
}
```

That ought to do it.