# How to write console output to a control within multi threading MVC modeled application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, model-view-controller, console, controls

I found a very simple and elegant way to direct console output to a textbox via this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802876/what-is-a-good-way-to-direct-console-output-to-text-box-in-windows-form), but now I don't find a way to implement it in my presenter class so that it works wherever I need it. This means in the main thread, but also in all the classes initiated in the main thread.

The problem is that the class I found online has a control (textbox) in it to which output is directed. In my presenter class, I cannot define controls. So when I start the presenter thread, which then starts the form in which I defined the TextWriter, output generated in the form is being written to the textbox as expected, but whenever I Console.Writeline in the presenter or in other instances created in the presenter, then it is still directed to the stadard debug output window...

I'm relatively new to MVC model, as you might already see. :)

So, TextBoxStreamWriter:

```
public class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextBox _output ;

    public TextBoxStreamWriter(TextBox output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        MethodInvoker action = 
            delegate 
            {
                _output.AppendText(value.ToString());
            };
        _output.BeginInvoke(action);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

In my presenter class:

```
public MTMainPresenter(IMTMainForm view)
{
  _view = view;
  HandleShizzle();
  Console.Writeline("Presenter initialized :( "); // << Doesn't work as I want it to...
}
```

program.cs:

```
private static MTMainPresenter _presenter;

static void Main()
{
  var mainForm = new MTMainForm();
  _presenter = new MTMainPresenter(mainForm);
  Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

In my form:

```
TextWriter _writer = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(txtboxConsole);
  Console.SetOut(_writer);
  Console.Writeline("Yay !"); // << Works fine, the way I want it to
}
```

So basically, I created a test button in the form that generated a Console.WriteLine() and this works just fine. But when I do the same in my presenter, it writes to the standard debug window. I tried already initializing the TextWriter in the Procgram.cs class, but since it has a TextBox control, that needs to be assigned, I'm a bit lost on how to solve this...

I'm quite sure this is so easy to fix, but I lack the experience.

Thanks a lot in advance
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. After thinking it through for a while and trying some things, I found a way to do it. There will probably be a much better way, so please correct me if this is not according to best practices. :) But it works...

I can now call Console.WriteLine() anywhere (MTMainForm, Presenter, any instances of custom objects inside my presenter...).

Steps I'm making...
1. Create the form
2. In the form, create writer linked to a control
3. back in Program.cs, get the created writer from the form
4. deviate the output to the writer
5. run the form...

Program.cs

```
static void Main()
{
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

     var mainForm = new MTMainForm();
     TextWriter wrt = mainForm.GetWriter();
     Console.SetOut(wrt);

     _presenter = new MTMainPresenter(mainForm);

     Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

MTMainForm:

```
TextBoxStreamWriter _writer = null;

public MTMainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(textBoxConsole);
}

public TextBoxStreamWriter GetWriter()
{
    return _writer;
}
```

TextBoxStreamWriter:

```
public class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextBox _output;

    public TextBoxStreamWriter(TextBox output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        MethodInvoker action =
            delegate
            {
                _output.AppendText(value.ToString());
                if (_output.Text.Length > 4000)
                    _output.Text = _output.Text.Substring(2000, _output.Text.Length - 2000);
            };
        _output.BeginInvoke(action);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```